# Application error the connection to the server was unsuccessful ionic 3

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3

Application error the connection to the server was unsuccessful ionic 3

I am getting this error While building for ionic 3 app which has google map installed.

And app hangs in the middle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Application error the connection to the server was unsuccessful ionic
>   3

I resolved it like this see if this helps you

In my `index.html` I removed the link

```
<script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"> </ script>
```

and in my `config.xml` file I added

```
<preference name="loadUrlTimeoutValue" value="700000" />
```